# Rationale behind std::bool_constant

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm wondering, what is the rationale behind introducing `std::bool_constant` and its subsequent use for `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` (as well as the comparison structs defined in header `<ratio>`, cf. N4389) in C++17?

Thus far I've only been able to locate the papers containing the wording:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4334.html
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4389.html

While both paper refer to a "rationale" -- https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51 -- the linked-to comment feed mostly states that this is "Based on the discussion on c++std-lib*" (presumably referring to the private reflector?) without going into further details.

Here is the the documentation:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant

Comment: My first thoguht too. Read up about SFINAE, this could be useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what SFINAE has to do with it?

Comment: @MarcAndreson: Well I failed to substitute "SFINAE" for a better idea, but that's not an error ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, can you come up with any reasonable example in which `bool_constant` should be used in conjunction with SFINAE? I can't, off the top of my head.

Comment: @Columbo: Refer to my previous comment, if you get a spare moment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I realize that SFINAE has not *much* to do with it, and you jokingly acknowledged that. I still want to know whether there is an example, just out of curiosity.

Comment: [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/) is in some sense a precursor to modern metaprogramming and it comes with [`mpl::bool_<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/bool.html) (as well as `mpl::int_` and so on), so the technique has a precedent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's pure syntactic sugar. Often, we use e.g. tag-dispatching like so:

```
template <typename T>
void foo_impl(T t, std::false_type) { /*Implementation for stuff (and char) */}
template <typename T>
void foo_impl(T t, std::true_type ) { /*Implementation for integers but not char*/}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    foo_impl(t, std::bool_constant<std::is_integral<T>{} && !std::is_same<char, T>{}>());
}
```

Without `bool_constant`, we'd have to use a longer type-specifier to designate the desired type: `std::integral_constant<bool, ...>`. Since the usage of `integral_constant` for boolean values pops up especially often, a concise and short way of adressing the specializations was asked for, and `bool_constant` provides that.
In fact, `bool_constant` is nothing more than an alias template for `bool`-specializations of `integral_constant`:

```
template <bool B>
using bool_constant = integral_constant<bool, B>;
```

The only reason the declarations for `true_type` and `false_type` (and other uses of `integral_constant<bool, ..>`) were altered is for brevity in the standard, even; There was no technical need, as `integral_constant<bool, false>` and `bool_constant<false>` designate the exact same type.

Comment: Whenever I repeatedly use `std::integral_constant` I end up writing aliases much like it; which is an argument for.  OTOH, I use `bool_t` instead of something that long.  Brevity is the something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And, yeah, I've already been using `std::integral_constant`, so the question had an implicit "as opposed to just using `std::integral_constant<bool, B>` as before" part, which you've also answered: Syntactic sugar & conciseness make sense :-)